# What is wrong with my ifstream method?

Tags: c++, file, oop, ifstream

In my class I have this ifstream method
I need it to read a file and write the information in my already created objects
Something is wrong with the code
First the a.engiene value is inserted with a space before the value - " gasoline"

And when the second object and third object are given values, the method does not assign the correct value for each attribute.

```
 friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& in, Auto &a)
        {
            char temp[31];
            temp[0] = '\0';
            in.getline(temp, 30, ':');

            if (temp[0])
            {
                in.getline(temp, 30, ':');
                delete[]a.engine;
                a.engine = new char[strlen(temp) + 1];
                strcpy(a.engine, temp);

                in.getline(temp, 30, ':');
                a.max_speed = atoi(temp);

                in.getline(temp, 30, ':');
                a.engine_cc = atoi(temp);

                in.getline(temp, 30, ':');
                a.avg_consumption_urban = atoi(temp);

                in.getline(temp, 30, ':');
                a.avg_speed_urban = atoi(temp);

                in.getline(temp, 30, ':');
                a.avg_consumption = atoi(temp);

                in.getline(temp, 30, ':');
                a.avg_speed = atoi(temp);

                return in;
            }
            else return in;
```

This is how I call the method in main:

```
        ifstream f1("autoc.txt", ios_base::in);
                f1 >> auto1 >> auto2 >> auto3;
```

This is the file data:

```
    auto1
    engine: gasoline
    max_speed: 250
    engine_cc: 1980
    avg_consumption_urban: 11
    avg_speed_urban: 50
    avg_consumption: 8
    avg_speed: 100
    auto2
    engine: diesel
    max_speed: 230
    engine_cc: 1600
    avg_consumption_urban: 9
    avg_speed_urban: 50
    avg_consumption: 6
    avg_speed: 80
    auto3
    engine: hybrid
    max_speed: 190
    engine_cc: 1450
    avg_consumption_urban: 7
    avg_speed_urban: 50
    avg_consumption: 4
    avg_speed: 90
```

This is the output window:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwuZz.jpg

This is not a duplicate to my other question.
I have this code that almost works. I need to make it assign the correct value to my attributes for each object.

Comment: What are you doing? You're supposed to **skip over** property names (reading until `:`) and **then** read the values. Please, get it right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From a file, how do I read from a certain point in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345349/from-a-file-how-do-i-read-from-a-certain-point-in-c)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. There I had a vague question. Here I have this code that I need to fix. It almost works. And how do I do what you said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in.getline(temp, 30, ':');
```

reads up to the `:`, which are the property names. You also want to extract the values after that, so you need to add

```
in.getline(temp, 30);
```

after each

```
in.getline(temp, 30, ':');
```

But bear in mind that your program completely ignores the property names and just goes by the order of values. I hope this solves your problems once and for all.

I'm afraid to add a neater version of doing this (you might again ask about), so I'll just mention it (like I did in the answer on your original question). It's about using `std::string temp;` and `std::getline` instead of `std::istream::getline`.

Comment: I added in.getline(temp, 30); like you said. And for starters it skips the first value, for the engine type. Still doesn't work properly.

Comment: I'm not sure what I have to replace to use string temp. I guess I have to replace my char temp[31] with just string temp;? and change in.getline(temp, 30, ':'); to what? getline(temp, 30, ':'); ?

Comment: Leave it be for now. **I've found the problem:** The first `in.getline(temp, 30, ':');` should be `in.getline(temp, 30);`. There's no `:` after `auto1` - or do you not understand the code you write?

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I hope in the future to look back on this and say maaan was I a big noob back then. But that's what I am now. Do you have any idea why it puts a space just before the value " gasoline", " diesel", " hybrid"? Thanks again

Comment: That's because there is one. You can `cin.ignore()` it, after `in.getline(temp, 30, ':');` or you can do `in.getline(temp, 30, ' ');` instead of `in.getline(temp, 30, ':');`... There are plenty of options (with `operator>>` involved, too).

Comment: It's like you said, I don't understand the code I write, well the new parts at least. And this getline is new to me. I'm trying to read as much as I can, but I get stuck sometimes. Thanks again

Comment: And I got rid of that spaces now. I have to see how other options I have with operator>> where can I find a good source of reference for that? Thanks

Comment: I don't know about that, experiment :)

Comment: Will do :) Thanks for the help again. I still have two more different files. I will try to solve it by myself. Failure is always an option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can delegate most of the parsing to the STL itself. The format of your "autos" seem to be fixed and have a set order, which greatly simplifies the approach to parsing (whether you are stuck to using "char [31]" is unclear, but if you are not you'd obviously be better off with std::string as it's the case with the "name" field I have added to the Auto struct)

A working sample:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct SeparatorReader: std::ctype<char>
{
    template<typename T>
    SeparatorReader(T &&seps):
        std::ctype<char>(get_table(seps), true) {}

    template<typename T>
    std::ctype_base::mask const *get_table(T &&seps) {
        auto rc = new std::ctype_base::mask[std::ctype<char>::table_size]();
        for(auto &sep: seps)
            rc[static_cast<unsigned char>(sep)] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};


struct Auto
{
    std::string name;
    char engine[31];
    int max_speed;
    int engine_cc;
    int avg_consumption_urban;
    int avg_speed_urban;
    int avg_consumption;
    int avg_speed;

    Auto(const std::string &name) : name(name) {}

    friend std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &is, Auto &a);
    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Auto &a);
};

std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &is, Auto &a)
{
    char tmp[31] = "";

    is >> tmp; is >> a.engine; // skip field name, read value
    is >> tmp; is >> a.max_speed;
    is >> tmp; is >> a.engine_cc;
    is >> tmp; is >> a.avg_consumption_urban;
    is >> tmp; is >> a.avg_speed_urban;
    is >> tmp; is >> a.avg_consumption;
    is >> tmp; is >> a.avg_speed;

    return is;
}

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Auto &a)
{
    os << a.name << std::endl;
    os << "engine: " << a.engine << std::endl;
    os << "max_speed: " << a.max_speed << std::endl;
    os << "engine_cc: " << a.engine_cc << std::endl;
    os << "avg_consumption_urban: " << a.avg_consumption_urban << std::endl;
    os << "avg_speed_urban: " << a.avg_speed_urban << std::endl;
    os << "avg_consumption: " << a.avg_consumption << std::endl;
    os << "avg_speed: " << a.avg_speed << std::endl;

    return os;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream stream(argv[1]);
    stream.imbue(std::locale(stream.getloc(), new SeparatorReader(" :\n")));

    std::string name;
    while(stream >> name) {
        Auto a(name);
        stream >> a;

        std::cout << "------------------------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << a;
    }
}
```

If we pass a sample file with your sample input ... the output is:

```
------------------------------
auto1
engine: gasoline
max_speed: 250
engine_cc: 1980
avg_consumption_urban: 11
avg_speed_urban: 50
avg_consumption: 8
avg_speed: 100
------------------------------
auto2
engine: diesel
max_speed: 230
engine_cc: 1600
avg_consumption_urban: 9
avg_speed_urban: 50
avg_consumption: 6
avg_speed: 80
------------------------------
auto3
engine: hybrid
max_speed: 190
engine_cc: 1450
avg_consumption_urban: 7
avg_speed_urban: 50
avg_consumption: 4
avg_speed: 90
```